# Prevent iTunes from Opening with Windows Start?

Tags: itunes, windows, startup

Everytime I boot my Windows 7 x64 PC, iTunes loads. I have iTunes 12.2.1.16. No iPad or iPhone is connected. I removed all iTunes entries from MSConfig startup, boot, and services. I also ran CCleaner just in case. I also use the Autorun Windows program to check on what's booting and running. Only Bonjour Services and the Apple Mobile Device USB driver are still active. It's not in the task scheduler either. Where the hell is it?

Comment: OP clearly states no iDevices connected.

Comment: See [this thread on Super User](http://superuser.com/q/355762/432665).  Maybe some insight.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Startup folder in the Start menu. Otherwise it could be an option that is built into iTunes' settings.